# Deny external SSH access to a user

Tags: ssh, security, users

Is it possible to deny access to a user (in my case `www-data`) from outside the network? Or possibly deny this:

```
ssh www-data@example.com
```

But allow this if already logged in:

```
su www-data
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excerpt from `man sshd`:

> Regardless of the authentication type, the account is checked to
>   ensure that it is accessible.  An account is not accessible if it is
>   locked, listed in `DenyUsers` or its group is listed in `DenyGroups`.

Run following command.

`echo "DenyUsers www-data" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

then restart `sshd`

I would suggest specifying only certain users that are allowed to log into the machine via ssh using `AllowUsers` directive so that all other users are denied.

`echo "AllowUsers valid_user1 valid_user2" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: It seems to be working. The reson I asked this was because someone hacked me in some way and used the user www-data to run this commands: /usr/sbin/fakeproc. This took up 100% on one core.

Comment: @Patrik `sshd`'s restart must have ended that session. I suggest you allow ssh access to only valid users using `AllowUsers` directive.

Comment: `AllowGroups` is another useful directive into that direction. @Sachin: A sshd restart will not terminate any running session.